# Why does excel crash here?

Tags: excel, vba, terminate

Is there any reason the below crashes excel 2016?

```
Option Explicit
Option Compare Text
Option Base 1

Sub p1()
    Dim t(1), w()
    t(1) = w
    If IsMissing(w) Then DoEvents
    If IsMissing(t(1)) Then DoEvents
End Sub
```

`w` is an uninitiated array, but passing `w` into `ismissing(w)` is fine, yet when passing it via the `t(1)`, excel reproducibly terminates ungracefully...

This is the shortest bit of code I have managed to generate using vba only that always kills the excel application (i.e. not using external code like `createobject` or `shell`).

Are there other such examples?

cheers

Comment: According the the event viewer, it's an access violation in combase.dll.  Without attaching a debugger to it, I'm guessing it's trying to free a null pointer in the data area of a doubly wrapped `Variant`. The `DoEvents` calls are a red herring though, as are the `Option` statements. If you're looking for "shortest", you can golf out at least 81 characters with assignments like `x = IsMissing(t(1))`. And that's without touching the whitespace.  :-P

Comment: `Public Sub Boom() : Dim a(1), b() : a(1) = b : a(1) = IsMissing(a(1)) : End Sub` ([chat transcript](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/47065066#47065066))

Comment: 'Sub plop(): Dim b(): IsMissing Array(b)(1):  End Sub`

Comment: Nope, `plop()` does not crash anything.

Comment: Ah, I had option base 1 specified.... try:  `Sub plop(): Dim b(): IsMissing Array(b)(0): End Sub`

Answer (score 17):

### tl;dr

You confused the hell out of `IsMissing` by making it think an uninitialized array was a malformed `ParamArray`, and hit a bug in its implementation.

---

According to the Windows event viewer, the underlying exception that brings down Excel is an access violation in vbe7.dll:

<sub>The first report in I saw (commented on above) was a Rubberduck callback failing because Excel was toast.</sub>

```
Faulting application name: EXCEL.EXE, version: 15.0.5067.1000, time stamp: 0x5b76360d
Faulting module name: VBE7.DLL, version: 7.1.10.68, time stamp: 0x58def301
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x00000000001cd38c
Faulting process id: 0xac4
Faulting application start time: 0x01d45de81ef072ed
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office15\EXCEL.EXE
Faulting module path: C:\PROGRA~1\COMMON~1\MICROS~1\VBA\VBA7.1\VBE7.DLL
```

The access violation is due to the VB run-time attempting to dereference a null pointer. This is the where the debugger lands you as it dies:

```
00007FFF9CDDD383  mov         rax,qword ptr [rsp+30h]  
00007FFF9CDDD388  mov         rax,qword ptr [rax+8]  
00007FFF9CDDD38C  movzx       eax,word ptr [rax]    <--fails, rax is 0.
00007FFF9CDDD38F  cmp         eax,1  
00007FFF9CDDD392  jne         00007FFF9CD7B8A4
```

---

So, let's take a look at what the [`IsMissing` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/ismissing-function) is checking for. VBA is basically a beast of COM, and an optional parameter that isn't passed is received by the called function as a `Variant` with a type of VT_ERROR per RPC convention. It isn't passed as `Null`, `Empty`, or any other VB construct. The following code demonstrates:

```
Sub Foo()
    Bar
End Sub

Sub Bar(Optional x)
    Debug.Print VarPtr(x)   'This has a valid pointer.
    Debug.Print IsError(x)  'True
    Debug.Print VarType(x)  '10 (vbError)
End Sub
```

<sub>You can read a slightly more technical explanation [on Raymond Chen's blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20140919-00/?p=44023).</sub>

---

`IsMissing` is *intended* to be passed an incoming parameter, so it also has to be aware of `ParamArray`s (under the hood, a `ParamArray` is just a `Variant()`). Although, if you don't give any parameters to it the procedure *still gets an array* - it just has a `UBound` lower than the `LBound`:

```
Sub Calling()
    Called
End Sub

Sub Called(ParamArray params())
    Debug.Print LBound(params)   '<-- 0
    Debug.Print UBound(params)   '<-- -1
End Sub
```

---

Here's where it gets interesting. You can't have both a `ParamArray` and an optional argument in the same procedure signature - it can be one or the other. When you look at the function signature, you'll see that it takes a pointer to a `Variant` (that is, it expects a `ByRef` parameter):

```
[entry(0x60000007), helpcontext(0x000f69b5)]
VARIANT_BOOL _stdcall IsMissing([in] VARIANT* ArgName);
```

But code like this doesn't give the function what it's expecting to see:

```
Sub DieExcelDie()
    Dim x(1), y()
    x(1) = y
    x(1) = IsMissing(x(1))
End Sub
```

`x(1)` has to be marshalled into a `ByRef Variant` to be passed as a parameter to `IsMissing`. So what it ***sees*** is an array of `Variant` that has both an `LBound` and `UBound` value of zero ([this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52341240/4088852) goes a bit into what an uninitialized array looks like in memory). The parameter has not already gone through the RPC mechanism, so a this point it is ***completely indistinguishable*** from a `ParamArray` containing one passed parameter. It would check to see if the variant was typed as VT_ERROR, see that it was an array, and attempt to process it that way. Since it doesn't comply with the spec for an empty parameter list, it likely checks to see what the first passed parameter was... by dereferencing the data area. The `SAFEARRAY` structure looks like this<sup>1</sup>:

[image: SAFEARRAY in memory]

Going back to the disassembly and without going completely down the rabbit hole of disassembling vbe7.dll, the `rax+8` on the previous instruction is most likely loading up the `pvData` pointer (it's 8 bytes on a 64 bit version of Excel), which you can see is zero.

---

This is simply a bug in the implementation of `IsMissing` - it should be checking for a null pointer instead of blindly dereferencing it. I suspect, although can't verify, that it was introduced in VB5 along with the changes that allowed both non-`Variant` optional parameters and default values.

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>Image was taken as a screenshot from [How Visual Basic 6 Stores Data](https://www.codeguru.com/vb/gen/vb_misc/algorithms/article.php/c7495/How-Visual-Basic-6-Stores-Data.htm) on codeguru.</sub>

Comment: Excellent, that is a very comprehensive answer based on indepth error analysis, and using tools I certainly dont have skills to use. Thank you!  For info, I hit this snag when trying to un-nest paramarrays.

Comment: @Comintern ... I'm in awe. Appreciate the answer ... it was enlightening.

Comment: @TechnoDabbler Thanks, that was [written on a dare](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/47064726#47064726). :-D

Comment: Superb! A technical tour de force!