# Calculate mode for a variable range set over until loop

Tags: excel, vba

I want to calculate mode for a range. 
Range is a variable based on a condition.

```
Value 1     Value 2     Output
A           10          10
A           12          10
A           10          10
B           5           3
B           3           3
B           2           3
B           3           3
```

Like in the above case:

I need to calculate the mode(column C), with the range of value 2(column B), with a condition that Value 1(column A)is same in the range.

```
Sub mode()

Dim count
Dim rng As Range

x = 2
Do While Range("A" & x).Value = Range("A" & x + 1).Value
     x = x + 1
Loop

Set rng = Range(Cells(x, 2), Cells(x + 1, 2))
md = WorksheetFunction.mode(rng)
Range("C" & x).Value = md

End Sub
```

Do You have any clue for that?

Comment: You can do this with a formula.

Comment: can you help with the formula ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your data are in A1:B7, then put this in C1 and copy down.

It's an array formula so needs to be confirmed with Ctrl, Shift and Enter, and curly brackets will appear round the formula.

```
=MODE(IF($A$1:$A$7=A1,$B$1:$B$7))
```

Of course, you could add the formula using VBA.

Answer (score 2):

Enter the following formula as array formula (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>) in cell C1 and pull it down

```
=MODE(IF(A:A=A1,B:B))
```

*<sup>Note: In newer Excel versions you might need to use the [MODE.SNGL function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/mode-sngl-function-f1267c16-66c6-4386-959f-8fba5f8bb7f8) instead.</sup>*

[image]
*<sup>Image 1: Column C uses the array formula with an IF condition.</sup>*

For further information see [Conditional mode with criteria](https://exceljet.net/formula/conditional-mode-with-criteria).

Answer (score 0):

For reference rather than the best answer, below is the VBA I wrote which completes the same task as the array formula from the other answers:

```
Sub mode2()
Dim lastrow As Long, x As Long, b As Long
Dim cel As Range, cel2 As Range
Dim rng() As Variant
b = 2
lastrow = Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
For Each cel In Range("A2:A" & lastrow)
    If cel.Value = cel.Offset(1, 0).Value Then
            If (Not Not rng) = 0 Then
                ReDim rng(0 To 0)
                rng(0) = cel.Offset(, 1).Value
            Else
                ReDim Preserve rng(0 To (cel.Row - b))
                rng(cel.Row - b) = cel.Offset(, 1).Value
        End If
    Else
        ReDim Preserve rng(0 To (cel.Row - b))
        rng(cel.Row - b) = cel.Offset(, 1).Value
        If (Not Not rng) <> 0 Then
            Range("C" & cel.Row).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.mode(rng)
            b = cel.Row + 1
            Erase rng()
        End If
    End If
Next cel
End Sub
```

This is probably not the cleanest or best macro, but it works and maybe it will help someone when a formula isn't an option. (at least it'll be useful for me if I ever go [code bowling](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-bowling))

Comment: Shouldn't `lastrow`, `x` and `b` be `Long` otherwise you have a lot of implicit conversions to `Long`? And just for my interest can you explain `Not Not rng`?

Comment: @Pᴇʜ You are correct, I'm not that experienced in VBA (yet) and without formal training I still keep mixing up my variable types. (believe me it has given me copious amounts of debugging grief, but I'll get there eventually). As for the Not Not rng, [I found this on another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45882516/11936678) and after some testing, found it works reliably in this case. I'll let them do the explaining as I probably won't do a good job.

Comment: Thanks for the link, interesting method (never seen it before).